# How to use a subset of animation.css animations?

Tags: css, animate.css

I want to use https://animate.style/. But it's more than 90 KBs in size.

I just want a very simple bouncing animation. That's all.

Apart from going into the source code and trying to recreate the bouncing keyframes and animations, is there another way to do so?

For example, in [Material UI](https://mui.com/), or in [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) only what you have used would be included in the final bundle.

Is there something similar for Animate.css too?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a simple bouncing animation, why not using your own `keyframes`?

Exemple falling down :

```css
@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-45px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
#my_little_square {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#f00;
  animation: myAnim 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_little_square">

</div>
```

Here is a little tool to help you start : https://webcode.tools/generators/css/keyframe-animation